# Excel : OR + VLOOKUP unable to detect some values

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet that has one sheet contains assignments of students in a semester and another sheet contains students name, the organization they belong to and their position.  I'm trying to recognize the top student from each assignment and find out what organization they are in and what position they are in the organization. My problem is I use or with VLOOKUP, but I can't get some of the student organization show. Could you please help. Thank you.[image: first sheet]

[image: second sheet]

Comment: If a student isn't listed in your lookup table (e.g. Robert) what do you hope to return from the formula?

Comment: Why vlookup(k5:m5, ... instead of vlookup(b5, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Use nested IFs like below:

```
=IF(K5 <> "", VLOOKUP(K5, Combine2B2!$A$2:$C$10, 2, FALSE), IF(L5 <> "", VLOOKUP(L5, Combine2B2!$A$2:$C$10, 2, FALSE), IF(M5 <> "", VLOOKUP(L5, Combine2B2!$A$2:$C$10, 2, FALSE), "")))
```

This is to lookup the ORG.

Answer (score 0):

The names are in column B regardless of whether they are in K:M or not.

```
 =if(len($k5&$l5&$m5), vlookup($b5, combine2b2!$a$2:$c$10, column(b:b), false), text(,))
```

Fill right and down.